# How to plot the distribution of a column grouped/colored by measurement in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a sample data frame like this:

```
Measurement <- c("Length","Breadth","Length","Breadth","Height",
                 "Height","Breadth","Length","Height","Breadth",
                 "Length","Height","Height","Breadth","Length")
Value <- c(45,43,45,100,62,62,43,74,74,74,12,17,17,44,12)
data <- data.frame(Measurement, Value)
```

I am trying to visualize this data to see how the values are distributed for each measurement and also if we combine the measurements. I am using a basic plot of histogram to do this but this is not visually appealing

```
hist(data$Value)
```

[image]

Could some one help me with ggplot2 or other advanced visualization to view this data better and I would like to **group by Measurements**. I would like to see if density plots can mean something here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A basic histogram may not be pretty, but that doesn't mean you're stuck with it in base R, e.g.: `palette(c("deepskyblue3", "darkorange2", "darkolivegreen3")); boxplot(Value ~ Measurement, data=data, xlab="Group", ylab="Value", col=1:3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple interesting options:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(factor(Measurement), Value)) + geom_violin(aes(fill = factor(Measurement)))
ggplot(data, aes(Value, colour = Measurement, group = Measurement)) + geom_density(fill=NA)
```

They produce the following:

[image: Violin Plot]

[image: Density Plot]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wonderful. This would be a good start for me and it looks beautiful in my larger data set. Thanks much @Mark :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possibility using `geom_histogram`. To get the best looking, most informative histogram, it is important to set the `binwidth` manually for every new data set.

```
library(ggplot2)

p = ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Value, fill=Measurement)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=1, colour="grey40", drop=TRUE) + 
    facet_grid(Measurement ~ ., margins=TRUE) +
    theme_bw()

ggsave("hist.png", plot=p, width=8, height=4, dpi=150)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the questions. Do you want to separate the values?
For that, you can do something like this:

```
ValueLength <- data.frame(Value = Value[which(Measurement == "Length")], Measurement = "Lenghth")
ValueBreadth <- data.frame(Value = Value[which(Measurement == "Breadth")], Measurement = "Breadth")
ValueHeight <- data.frame(Value = Value[which(Measurement == "Height")], Measurement = "Height")
```

Then you can combine them in one data frame again:

```
Values <- rbind(ValueLength, ValueBreadth, ValueHeight)
```

And plot with ggplot:

```
ggplot(Values, aes(Value, fill = Measurement)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
```

[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H3vN.png)